# write with PortAudio into fifo and read with ffmpeg on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, ffmpeg, fifo, portaudio

What I am trying to do:

1. open my microphone as audio source in PortAudio (works)
2. write stream into fifo (works)
3. read fifo with ffmpeg (dosen't work)

In PortAudio I am using the Blocking I/O like here:
http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/blocking_read_write.html

In the loop I write into the fifo like this:

```
int data = write('/tmp/aaa', sampleBlock, bufferSize);
```

when I read it to PortAudio write buffer it works.

```
bytes_read = read('/tmp/aaa', readSampleBlock, bufferSize);
err = Pa_WriteStream(stream, readSampleBlock, bufferSize)
```

when I read it with ffmpeg on console:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/aaa -f s16le -acodec copy -f nut -ar 48000 -ac 2 -v debug -report -acodec copy out.wav
```

It just blocks the loop and that's it.

Can anybody help me figure out what do I need to do?

My code:

```
#define SAMPLE_SIZE (1)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (480)
#define AUDIOFIFO "/tmp/aaa"

char *sampleBlock = NULL;
int status, captured_bytes, fifo, bytes_read;


err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream,
                    &inputParameters,
                    NULL,
                    48000,
                    FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                    paClipOff,
                    NULL, /* no callback, use blocking API */
                    NULL ); /* no callback, so no callback userData */
if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

numBytes = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * numChannels * SAMPLE_SIZE ;
sampleBlock = (char *) malloc( numBytes );
memset( sampleBlock, SAMPLE_SILENCE, numBytes );

if (status = mkfifo(AUDIOFIFO, 0666) < 0) 
{ 
  printf("Error making AUDIOFIFO: %s \n", strerror(errno)); 
}
err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
if( err != paNoError )
{
  goto error;
} 

fifo = open(AUDIOFIFO, O_RDWR, O_NONBLOCK);
if (fifo < 0) printf("Error opening AUDIOFIFO: %s \n", strerror(errno));

for( i=0; i<(60*48000)/FRAMES_PER_BUFFER; ++i )
{   
  if ((err = Pa_ReadStream(stream, sampleBlock, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)) != paNoError)
  {
    goto xrun;
  }  
  captured_bytes = write(fifo, sampleBlock, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
  if (captured_bytes < 0) 
  { 
    printf("Error writing to AUDIOFIFO: %s \n", strerror(errno));
  }

  framesProcessed += bufferSize;
}
```

Comment: Try playing a few seconds of data into the fifo, and just reading it with `wc -c /tmp/aaa` and it will tell you how many bytes it manages to read. If that seems sensible, try again but this time use `cat /tmp/aaa > /tmp/data` and then try running `file /tmp/data` to see if its format can be identified, and try `xxd /tmp/data | more` to see if you recognise the format.

Comment: it reads exactly the size of the buffer (8640 bytes). `file /tmp/data` gives back `/tmp/data: data` and the content dose not say much to me, bunch of hex.

Comment: What is the size of `/tmp/data`?

Comment: `wc -c /tmp/data`
`8640 /tmp/data`

Comment: I think you need to post your code...  at least a minimum, complete, verifiable version. It looks like you are only writing a single buffer which will likely hang `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I edited the question with my code. When I first open the fifo with `cat /tmp/aaa > /tmp/data` and then start my App cat reads much more data, so the loop is working and its also not blocking. The data that I send just doesn't make any sense to ffmpeg

Comment: You’ve opened it non-blocking.

Comment: My impression was that when I open it non-blocking then I can just start to send stuff into it and to worry about reading. Anyways, I tried both the behaviour is the same. When I start my App and then read with `cat` then it reads only the first buffer and exits, when I start reading with `cat`  and then start my app it reads all of the data. But the data is not recognizable for ffmpeg.

Comment: AFAIK, you must describe your input stream to `ffmpeg` **before** opening it, so I think the `-f s16le` at least must come **before** `-i /tmp/aaa` on your `ffmpeg` command line.

Comment: duh.. can you post that as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Hopefully that means you are up and running? If so, cool - well done and good luck with your project.

Comment: yes, thank you, the sound is a little funny but I will get it eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the general format for **ffmpeg** command-lines is:

```
ffmpeg <GLOBAL OPTIONS> <INPUT OPTIONS> -i INPUT <OUTPUT OPTIONS> OUTPUT
```

i.e. you must describe your input stream to **ffmpeg** *before* opening it.

So I think the `-f s16le` (at least) must come before `-i /tmp/aaa` on your **ffmpeg** command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -f s16le -i /tmp/aaa ....
```